# Where are Full-Text indexes in SSMS 2008 R2

Tags: full-text-search, ssms

I created a new database, a few tables, and full-text index & catalog using SQL Server Management Studio without any problem.  I wanted to copy the T-SQL creation scripts for each of those to include them in my documentation.  I can get the creation scripts for the database, tables, foreign keys, and the catalog but I can't seem to find the full-text index.  I've checked the related table's **Script Table As**->**CREATE To** and it's not there, nor is it with the Catalog.  Any ideas?  Is it because I'm only running SQL Server Standard edition?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In SSMS

- Tools
- Options
- "SQL Server Object Explorer"
- "Script full text catalogs"

Default is "false"...

Comment: I actually needed the indexes so I enabled **Table and view options** -> **Script full-text indexes** but you lead me right to it.  Thanks!